# Website is not loading index.php and showing index of folder

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php, lamp, webserver

[image: index of folder image]

As you can see my website has an `index.php` file but it is not opening it by default.

I have edited `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`. Here is the file's content:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

The issue happens only with this folder. All other folders open their `index.php` files properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the name of the Index.php file to index.php. Linux servers are case-sensitive. The index.html, index.htm, or index.php file names must be in all lowercase in order to be found. If the server finds no index, it will show a list of files.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines inside your configuration file:

```
<Directory /var/www/azgor.com/>
Options +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In my case the configuration file is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/azgor.conf`.

Then restart Apache using:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```